# subversion: equivalent of forcing a tag in cvs

Tags: svn, cvs

The build process at my company works as follows using CVS:

1. Create a release branch e.g. B_Release_1_0
2. Tag this branch with a release tag R_Release_1_0
3. Any small fix to the release will be committed to the release branch and we would force the tag to R_Release_1_0. If a larger fix were made to the branch we'd increment the tag.

In Subversion I can't see an equivalent way of doing this without having to manually copy the modified files from the branch folder to the tag folder as described here:
http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2005-05/0345.shtml

However this would be time consuming and error prone if multiple files were modified.

Is there a better way to force tags in Subversion or do we just have to change our approach entirely?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to recopy that branch to the tag. Not only will Subversion *retag* everything, but unlike CVS, it will store the history of your renaming.

However, I would recommend a few things...

- Simplify your branch and tag names. In CVS, branches and tags shared the same namespace. In Subversion, they don't. You don't need the `R` and `B` prefixes.
- Get rid of the underscores. You can use dots in Subversion. For example, your release can now be Release-1.0 instead of Release_1_0. Heck, I wouldn't even bother with the `Release` part. Just call the tag `1.0` and the branch `1.0`.

Now, for the main thing: Don't reuse tags! No, no, no. This is what is called in the CM community an *anti-pattern*. An *anti-pattern* is a bad CM practice.

It's not as bad moving a tag in Subversion as it is in CVS since Subversion, unlike CVS keeps a history of your tags and changes. However, a tag should be a snapshot in a particular point in time. That is, when I talk about Release 1.0, I don't have to say *"Do you mean Release 1.0 we did last week, or the week before"*.

I understand what you're doing, but there are better ways. First of all, tagging in Subversion is very, very quick. You do a `svn cp...` and you're done. In CVS, it could take 40 to 50 minutes (which is probably the reason you started the tag reuse business).

I recommend you simply append something to the end of the tag. For example, you could put something like: 1.0-2012-Feb-29, so you know you're talking about Release 1.0 that took place on Feb 29, 2012. You still know it's Release 1.0 because it still starts with 1.0, but you know **which** Release 1.0 you're talking about.

The big question is why are you labeling these releases? In Subversion, many people simply use the Subversion revision Id as a quick tag. You can talk about Revision 20321 of your software. Then, you only tag when you actually do an actual release.

We use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) as our build system, so there is a separate build for each commit. QA takes our builds right out of Jenkins for testing. Our developers simply say, take Build #29 of Release 1.0 (Release 1.0 is just a reference to the branch). Later on QA will say they've certified a particular build for release, and we'll go back into Jenkins and tag that particular build as Release-1.0 or whatever.

At my last place, we did tag each build as Release-1.0-B-xxx where "xxx" was the Jenkins build number. We put these build tags under `/project/tags/BUILDS/` in our Subversion repository, so they wouldn't show up when you wanted to do a `svn ls /project/tags` to see what the releases are. Then, when we actually had a release, we'd copy the build tag to the actual release tag:

```
$ svn cp http://build/src/foo/tags/BUILDS/1.0-B-233 http://build/src/foo/tags/1.0
```

I hope this helps. Subversion takes care of a lot of the issues you had with CVS. Tagging is instantaneous, every change in the repository has a revision number across the whole repository, and you can simply use that as a build tag. Plus, even when you move a tag, Subversion tracks the change, when it was made, and who made it. You could even ask the diff between the new and old tag.

However, tags should be immutable. I even have a pre-commit hook that allows you to create tags, but not modify them once they're set.

Answer (score 0):

change your approach: you are releasing a set of binaries, and then releasing a different set of binaries that pretend to be the same thing. This is not good practice.

So, given that you are going to change, its trivial to create a release branch in SVN - you copy to a different directory and you're done. Copying is cheap so go ahead and do it lots of times. The only problem you will have is that you will get a lot of branched directories, but you could delete old ones as you go.

Once you've made fixes to the release branch (hmm, but ok) then you have to merge the changes back onto your trunk - this is easy and should be as simple as merging the entire directory from tag branch to trunk. Only the files that were changed will be part of the merge as SVN uses a patch-and-apply mechanism to perform merges, only the changes that were made are applied to the trunk.

Alternatively, you can make your fixes to trunk and merge them onto your release branch, but although you can do this solely for the individual revision containing your fixes, this has the risk that your trunk code has changed significantly which would make the merge difficult.

Your third option is just to branch your release branch to a new release branch and make the fixes there. Note that SVN has atomic revision numbers, so you could apply fixes directly to your release branch and just note down the 2 sets of revision numbers - R_Release_1_0 v 1 is the original, R_Release_1_0 v2 is the fixed one, but like I said at the beginning its not best practise to do this(TBH this is what we do, it works for us so I'm not going to criticise it, you just need to understand exactly what and why you're doing).